# SpriteKit Add Child not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I had a general SKScene where I created a SKSpriteNode, added it via

```
[self addChild:_charecter];
```

And all was well..

I tried making a new class for the SKSpriteNode so that I could add some custom methods to it. Here is it's init method:

```
- (instancetype)init
{
  if (self = [super init]) {
    SKTexture *run1 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"run1"];
    SKTexture *run2 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"run2"];
    SKTexture *run3 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"run3"];
    _charecterSprites = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:run1, run2, run3, nil];

    self.texture = run1;
    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:1.0]; //CHANGE THIS LATER
  }
  return self;
}
```

The problem is that now when I add the _charecter to the view, it doesn't appear. I'm adding him in the SKScene as follows:

```
_charecter = [[RUNPlayer alloc] init];
_charecter.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CHARECTER_Y_AXIS);

self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -10.0/150.0);

[self addChild:_charecter];
```

Any idea why my SKSpriteNode isn't visible?
Thanks

Comment: It's charActer not charEcter ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying using one of the SKSpriteNode initializers instead of init

```
- (instancetype)initWithImageNamed:(NSString *)name
{
  if (self = [super initWithImageNamed:name]) {
    SKTexture *run1 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"run1"];
    SKTexture *run2 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"run2"];
    SKTexture *run3 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"run3"];
    _charecterSprites = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:run1, run2, run3, nil];

    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:1.0]; //CHANGE THIS LATER
  }
  return self;
}
```

From what I understand, when you use `initWithImageNamed:`, the sprite node's size is set to the texture's size.  Your sprite could of been on screen but had a size of (0,0).  Let us know if this works!

On a side note, check out Ray's tutorial on texture atlases to replace `_characterSprites` http://www.raywenderlich.com/45152/sprite-kit-tutorial-animations-and-texture-atlases